# Reading to object from .in file

Tags: c++

Hello i'm having a list of 3 int's spaced by 2 white-spaces, and i want to read them and create  an object. I will paste my code from data strucutre, class and pre/post data. I cant find the reason for the error. Any help is welcome:

Class.h:

```
class RAngle{
private:
    int x,y,l,b; 
    int solution,prec;
    RAngle(){
        x = y = solution = prec = b = l = 0;
    }

    RAngle(int i,int j,int k){
        x = i;
        y = j;
        l = k;
        solution = 0; prec=0; b=0;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const RAngle& ra){
        out << ra.x << " " << ra.y<<" " << ra.l <<endl;
        return out;
    }

    friend istream& operator >>( istream& is, RAngle& ra){
        is >> ra.x;
        is >> ra.y;
        is >> ra.l;

        return is ;
    }

};
```

dataStructure.h:

```
template <class T>
class List
{
private:
    struct Elem
    {
        T data;
        Elem* next;
    };

    Elem* first;

    void push_back(T data){
    Elem *n = new Elem;
    n->data = data;
    n->next = NULL;
    if (first == NULL)
    {
        first = n;
        return ;
    }
    Elem *current;
    for(current=first;current->next != NULL;current=current->next);
    current->next = n;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
void readData(List <RAngle> &l){
    *RAngle r;
    int N;
    ifstream f_in;
    ofstream f_out;

    f_in.open("ex.in",ios::in);
    f_out.open("ex.out",ios::out);

    f_in >> N;
    for(int i=0;i<13;++i){
        f_in >> r;
        cout << r;
        l.push_back(r);
    }

    f_in.close();
    f_out.close();
}*
```

input data:

```
3 1 2
1 1 3
3 1 1
```

output(at printing when reading):

```
1 2 1
1 3 3
1 1 3
```

As you can see somehow it starts reading with 2-nd position and finishes with first.

Comment: Is this the entirety of your code?  Your classes seemed to be named oddly; usually the file that contains `class Foo` is called `Foo.h` or `Foo.cpp`, etc.  And although you give us a file named `main.cpp`, you have no `main()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As you can see somehow it starts reading with 2-nd position and finishes with first.

That's because you extract the first value.

In `readData` function:

```
f_in >> N;    //  This line will extract the first value from the stream.

// the loop starts at the second value
for(int i=0;i<13;++i){
f_in >> r;
    cout << r;
    l.push_back(r);
}
```

Comment: thank you. i tought that fn >> N wil lcount my lines it seems i was wrong:<

Answer (score 1):

The line that reads `f_in >> N` is reading a count into a variable first, but your input file lacks that count. (Or rather, it sees the first '3' as the count, which means that the tuples actually start with '1 2 1 ...').